# How to set a default Calendar in iCal 10.7.2

Tags: macos, ical

Since I activated iCloud, iCal has changed the default calendar to new events to one which I do not want to use.

How can I change the default calendar for iCal? I cannot find a setting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in iCal's preferences:

**Preferences > General > Default Calendar**.

This enables the default calendar to be set.

[image: Default Calendar]